# How can I group many values for a variable in grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-dashboard

I have an SQL table with columns: name and user type.

| Name | type |
| --- | --- |
| John | student |
| Tom | teacher |
| Peter | teacher |
| Steve | student |

I want to have a grafana variable where I can select a user "type" and the variable passes the value of all the "names" corresponding to that "type" to the dashboard.

I found this example - https://grafana.com/blog/2019/07/17/ask-us-anything-how-to-alias-dashboard-variables-in-grafana-in-sql/ which lets me alias a one to one mapping, but I am looking for a one to many mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in two steps:

First, per your example create variable, that will contain types.

Than, in the same way create variable, that will contain names, and will use firs variable as parameter for select.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to create 2 variables and link them in next order:

1. Create variable "type", "select distinct type from my_table"
2. Create variable "Name", "select distinct name from my_table where  type = $type", where $type is already your variable from grafana.